# iis web.config inheritance when running 64bit win 2k8 with 32/64 bit worker processes

Tags: iis, 64-bit, 32-bit

My understanding of how web.config settings are inherited (to the site level) on a 64bit server2k is as below, but I think maybe I am wrong...

```
For app-pools where "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is set to "False":
    Use the config files from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\config dir

For app-pools where "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is set to "True": 
    Use the config files from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\config dir
```

The only think is, I've set up a custom default level (based on medium trust) in my \Framework\ web.config, but sites running with Enable 32-Bit Applications=False seem to be affected by it (i.e. are getting security permissions, but should be in Full Trust). Have I got the wrong end of the stick?